# spock doesn't return mocked respons if an empty string is passed

Tags: groovy, spock

```
class Foo {
 def getSomeFood(def param){
 //do some stuff
 }
```

When you mock this in a spec

```
  def foo=Mock()
```

and make the method return something

```
 foo.getSomeFood(_) >> "apple"
```

if this class is being used inside another class like

```
foo.getSomeFood("")
```

it returns null rather than "apple"

It could be a bug in spock.... Does anybody have any idea why it doesn't return any data?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a minimal self-contained example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the problem. What i was doing is that in _given_ block I have `foo.getSomeFood(_)>> "apple"` and in _then_ then block I have `1 * foo.getSomeFood("")` which was invalidating the statement in _given_ block

Comment: Right. See the [explanation](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#combining-mocking-and-stubbing) in the Gradle docs.

Comment: @peter-niederwieser Why you didn't post your answers? They helped me but I can't upvote them because they are absent. :-/